# How to combine some elements of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

In order to simplify my expression, I face a list manipulation problem.

For example, given the input list

```
list = {a[1] cof[1], a[2] cof[2], a[3] cof[3], a[4] cof[4], a[5] cof[5], a[6] cof[6]};
```

I can calculate the values of `f[a[i]]` and then combine the idential elements (`f[]` is just a function of the `a[]`). The condition of this transformation is

```
f[a[1]] == f[a[3]] == f[a[6]]; f[a[2]] == f[a[4]];
```

so that the output list becomes

```
newlist = {(cof[1] + cof[3] + cof[6]) a[1], (cof[2] + cof[4]) a[2], cof[5] a[5]};
```

How can I get this kind transformation to newlist for the general case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with your `list` and a dummy `f` that produces output with the equivalences you specified:

```
list = {a[1] cof[1], a[2] cof[2], a[3] cof[3], a[4] cof[4], a[5] cof[5], a[6] cof[6]};

f[a[1] | a[3] | a[6]] = "one";
f[a[2] | a[4]] = "two";
```

We might proceed:

```
GatherBy[list, f /@ Cases[#, _a] &]
```

> ```
> {{a[1] cof[1], a[3] cof[3], a[6] cof[6]}, {a[2] cof[2], a[4] cof[4]}, {a[5] cof[5]}}
> ```

```
GatherBy[#, Head] & /@ List @@@ Join @@@ %
```

> ```
> {{{a[1], a[3], a[6]}, {cof[1], cof[3], cof[6]}},
>  {{a[2], a[4]}, {cof[2], cof[4]}}, {{a[5]}, {cof[5]}}}
> ```

```
First[#] Total[#2] & @@@ %
```

> ```
> {a[1] (cof[1] + cof[3] + cof[6]), a[2] (cof[2] + cof[4]), a[5] cof[5]}
> ```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful for me.In your second step, can you change it a little for a general case.Because cof[i_] is not a single Integer or Symbol, for example, cof[i_] := g[i] coff[i] const.

Comment: @Orders Does `GatherBy[#, Head@# === a &]` work for you?  Also, be aware that `GatherBy` lists element groups by the order in which they first appear so if `a[*]` is not always first the third step will break; you may need to add a sort.  If you include a more complex example in your question I'll try to address it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for your help. You method is very general and it works for me now.  Yes, I am dealing a complex expression, at least for me. I am facing a problem for simplification for large expression. If I cannot deal with it myself, I will post it again.

Comment: @Orders Okay, no problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to dislike `GatherBy` as I do.

```
list = {a[1] cof[1], a[2] cof[2], a[3] cof[3], a[4] cof[4], a[5] cof[5], a[6] cof[6]};
```

Now similar to Mr. Wizard we define a function `f` which works as you suggest.

```
f[a[1] | a[3] | a[6]] = 1;
f[a[2] | a[4]] = 2;
f[_] := 0
```

And a second helper function `g` which does the actual work.

```
g[{0, expr_}] := expr
g[{i_, expr_}] := a[i]*Total[Cases[expr, _*r_cof :> r]]
```

Finally we put it all together...

```
With[{mask = f /@ Cases[list, a[r_]*_ :> a[r]]},
   g[{#, Pick[list, mask, #]}] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[mask]
 ]

(*{a[1] (cof[1] + cof[3] + cof[6]), a[2] (cof[2] + cof[4]), {a[5] cof[5]}} *)
```

Comment: Andy, +1 for a nice method, but why the dislike of `GatherBy`?  Also, would `a[r_]*__` (emphasis `__`) make this more general?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I suppose the __ would make it more general. I don't like `GatherBy` because it tends to be too slow for my taste. It may well have improved but my initial impression wasn't a good one.

Comment: Strange; `Tally` and `GatherBy` have always seemed *fast* to me, compared to what I used before they were introduced.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Tally` is incredibly fast, no complaints there (unless you want to transpose it). `GatherBy` I've never been happy with.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example where `GatherBy` is slow and a faster alternative?  I know one is if the compare function is much faster in vector mode; anything else?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard now that you mention it, it seems it has either improved in recent versions or I can't remember where I was running into poor performance...

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty clumsy way but it works:

```
# /. a[_] -> First@Cases[#, a[_], 2, 1] & /@ Apply[Plus, 
       GatherBy[list, f@First@Cases[#, a[_], 1, 1] &],1]//Simplify
```

Step by step:

```
list = {a[1] cof[1], a[2] cof[2], a[3] cof[3], a[4] cof[4], a[5] cof[5], a[6] cof[6]};
f[x_a] := MemberQ[{1, 3, 6}, First@x]

(* For each element of the list it picks out the first (and only) a[i]
   and applies f to it. Then does what the function name suggests *)
gb=GatherBy[list, f@First@Cases[#, a[_], 1, 1] &]
(* {{a[1] cof[1], a[3] cof[3], a[6] cof[6]},
    {a[2] cof[2], a[4] cof[4], a[5] cof[5]}} *)

(* Add the elemens of each group *)
ap=Apply[Plus,gb,1]
(* {a[1] cof[1] + a[3] cof[3] + a[6] cof[6], 
    a[2] cof[2] + a[4] cof[4] + a[5] cof[5]} *)

(* For each group replace all a[i] with just the first one *)
rep = # /. a[_] -> First@Cases[#, a[_], 2, 1] & /@ ap
(* {a[1] cof[1] + a[1] cof[3] + a[1] cof[6], a[2] cof[2] + a[2] cof[4] + a[2] cof[5]} *)

 Simplify@rep
 (* {a[1] (cof[1] + cof[3] + cof[6]), a[2] (cof[2] + cof[4] + cof[5])} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to write a compact version. Your initial data:

```
l = {a[1] cof[1], a[2] cof[2], a[3] cof[3], a[4] cof[4], a[5] cof[5], a[6] cof[6]};
p = {f[a[1]] == f[a[3]] == f[a[6]], f[a[2]] == f[a[4]]};
```

And then just:

```
List @@ Simplify[ Total[l /. Flatten[Thread[# -> #[[1]]] & /@ (List @@@ p /. f@x_ -> x)]]]

(*
{a[2] (cof[2] + cof[4]), a[5] cof[5], a[1] (cof[1] + cof[3] + cof[6])}
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 list = Array[a[#] cof[#] &, {6}];

 Simplify /@ Total /@ GatherBy[#, #[[1, 1]] &] &@
   MapAt[# /. Join[Thread[{1, 3, 6} -> 1], Thread[{2, 4} -> 2]] &, list, {All, 1}]
```

or

```
 Collect[#, a[_]] & /@ Total /@ GatherBy[#, #[[1, 1]] &] &[
   list /. {PatternSequence[a[1 | 3 | 6] x_] :> a[1] x, 
        PatternSequence[a[2 | 4] x_] :> a[2] x}]
 (* {a[1] (cof[1] + cof[3] + cof[6]), a[2] (cof[2] + cof[4]), a[5] cof[5]} *)
```