# Combining the items with common available dates from two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of data including dates such as

```
data1 = {{{yy, mm, dd}, a}, ...}
data2 = {{{yy, mm, dd}, A}, ...}
```

There are some missing dates from each list, but I want to have the data which are only available in both lists and combine them like this:

```
data3 = {{{yy ,mm, dd}, a, A}, ...}
```

Comment: Have a look at `Gather` or `GatherBy`, it might do most of the job.

Comment: I am marking this as "already answered" because I believe it is.  Also see: [(20040)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20040/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows b.gatessucks suggestion.

First, some data.  `data1` has 10 items; `data2` has 7 items, each of which was collected on the same date as its counterpart in `data1`.

```
data1 = Table[{{2010, 12, k}, a}, {k, 10}]
data2 = Drop[data1, {4, 7}] /. a -> A
```

Then join and process. 
(I'm assuming there `data1`, `data2` each have at most no more than one piece of data for a given date. )
`Cases` selects data pairs having the same date and returns the information in the desired format.

```
Cases[GatherBy[Join[data1, data2], First], {{w_, x_}, {w_, z_}} :> {w, x, z}]
```

> {{{2010, 12, 1}, a, A}, {{2010, 12, 2}, a, A}, {{2010, 12, 3}, a, 
>     A}, {{2010, 12, 8}, a, A}, {{2010, 12, 9}, a, A}, {{2010, 12, 10}, 
>     a, A}}