# Extracting only complete records from two data sets and combining them

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two data sets:

```
data1 =
{
  {{2004, 1, 1}, 28.0774}, {{2004, 1, 2}, 33.0775}, {{2004, 1, 3}, 33.6817}, 
  {{2004, 1, 4}, 31.41}, {{2004, 1, 5}, 31.6763}, {{2004, 1, 6}, 28.255}, 
  {{2004, 1, 7}, 29.4663}, {{2004, 1, 8}, 28.8583}, {{2004, 1, 9}, 27.3979}, 
  {{2004, 1, 10}, 26.2367}, {{2004, 1, 11}, 25.9692}, {{2004, 1, 12}, 28.7213}, 
  {{2004, 1, 13}, 27.405}, {{2004, 1, 14}, 27.6808}, {{2004, 1, 15}, 29.0129}, 
  {{2004, 1, 16}, 28.65}, {{2004, 1, 17}, 27.6096}, {{2004, 1, 18}, 27.1733}, 
  {{2004, 1, 19}, 30.3533}, {{2004, 1, 20}, 32.5442}, {{2004, 1, 21}, 35.2171}, 
  {{2004, 1, 22}, 35.7233}, {{2004, 1, 23}, 31.0108}, {{2004, 1, 24}, 27.9142}, 
  {{2004, 1, 25}, 26.8617}, {{2004, 1, 26}, 30.0146}, {{2004, 1, 27}, 30.4133}, 
  {{2004, 1, 28}, 29.8754}, {{2004, 1, 29}, 29.8067}, {{2004, 1, 30}, 29.7713}, 
  {{2004, 1, 31}, 27.4904}, {{2004, 2, 1}, 28.6221}, {{2004, 2, 2}, 30.9058}, 
  {{2004, 2, 3}, 28.1475}, {{2004, 2, 4}, 27.0221}, {{2004, 2, 5}, 26.9771}, 
  {{2004, 2, 6}, 26.5542}, {{2004, 2, 7}, 25.5142}, {{2004, 2, 8}, 25.7975}, 
  {{2004, 2, 9}, 28.3658}, {{2004, 2, 10}, 30.0617}
}
data2 =
{
  {{2004, 1, 2}, ""}, {{2004, 1, 5}, 33.71}, {{2004, 1, 6}, 33.54}, 
  {{2004, 1, 7}, 33.57}, {{2004, 1, 8}, 34.27}, {{2004, 1, 9}, 34.38}, 
  {{2004, 1, 12}, 34.92}, {{2004, 1, 13}, 34.26}, {{2004, 1, 14}, 34.62}, 
  {{2004, 1, 15}, 33.61}, {{2004, 1, 16}, 35.16}, {{2004, 1, 19}, ""}, 
  {{2004, 1, 20}, 36.21}, {{2004, 1, 21}, 35.53}, {{2004, 1, 22}, 35.12}, 
  {{2004, 1, 23}, 34.94}, {{2004, 1, 26}, 34.41}, {{2004, 1, 27}, 33.99}, 
  {{2004, 1, 28}, 33.63}, {{2004, 1, 29}, 32.86}, {{2004, 1, 30}, 33.16}, 
  {{2004, 2, 2}, 34.02}, {{2004, 2, 3}, 34.2}, {{2004, 2, 4}, 33.06}, 
  {{2004, 2, 5}, 33.26}, {{2004, 2, 6}, 32.49}, {{2004, 2, 9}, 32.91}, 
  {{2004, 2, 10}, 34.03}
}
```

Sometimes values are missing and sometime both values and dates are missing. I need just the records that are complete and common to both data sets.

```
data = Transpose[{data1value, data2value}];
mixeddata = {{Date}, data1value, data2value};
```

How could I write the code for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17731/handling-holidays-in-financial-time-series).

Comment: @RodLm on that problem they want to add the missing data as well which I dont want that.The questions are not the same.

Comment: I don't see how this question differs materially from your previously asked and answered [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27868/)

Comment: @m_goldberg it differs.For an starter who has a lot of things to do and at the same time debug the previous problem to solve new cases it differs.I am learning and solving my problems at the same time and you can see here commands are totally different.I know they are boring to you as professionals; but thanks for understanding.

Comment: "you as professionals" -- what a joke! Read my profile  to see how much of a professional I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some code I have found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141840/conditional-data-merging-in-mathematica) and used frequently:

```
MergeTables[data1_, data2_, pos1_, pos2_] := Cases[data1, x:{{__},_Real} :> Block[
    {y = Cases[data2, z:{{__},_Real} /; z[[pos2]] == x[[pos1]]]},
    Sequence @@ (Join[x, Delete[#, Thread@{pos2}]] & /@ y)
    ]
]
```

**EDIT:** now skipping empty entries by using x:{{__},*Real} as the pattern, not just x*.

For your example, usage would be `MergeTables[data1,data2,1,1]`.

This will yield one list with entries `{{date}, value1, value2}`. If you need to separate your values into two lists again, you can use `Transpose@list[[All,2;;]]`.

Comment: Nice start! However he doesn't want to select dates with empty values in one the tables.

Comment: Well... let's just adjust the Cases pattern then.

Comment: @TheoTiger many thanks nice codes!

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid my solution may not taste much like *Mathematica*, but it will do the job.
Here the trick is done by using `NumberQ`. `NumberQ` first ensures if there is a valid data value in first data file for a date; and then the `Do` loop search for the same date in second file. If the same date is present in the second file then `NumberQ` again checks if there is a data value and finally store the result in `data`. `ndata` is the number of final data.

```
ndata1 = Length[data1];
ndata2 = Length[data2];
(*To find the # of data in each file*)

k = 1;
Table[
 If[
  NumberQ[data1[[i]][[2]]] == True , (*NumberQ checks if there is a data*)
  Do[
   If[NumberQ[data2[[j]][[2]]] == True  && data2[[j]][[1]] == data1[[i]][[1]], 
    data[k] = {data2[[j]][[1]], data1[[i]][[2]], data2[[j]][[2]]}; k++; Break[]
   ], {j, 1, ndata2}
  ]
 ], {i, 1, ndata1}
]; ndata = k - 1;

newdata = Table[data[i], {i, 1, ndata}]
```

You can separate the data values as well

```
datavalue=Table[{data[i][[2]],data[i][[3]]}, {i, 1, ndata}]
```

Comment: Indeed, in Mathematica you would only iterate through lists on rare occasions. Try to use `Map` (`/@`) if you want to operate on each element of a list, and make use of patterns. You can use `Length` to get the length of the first dimension of a list.

Comment: @TheoTiger the codes wont work in my com by the way

Comment: Thanks @TheoTiger. Although I am not sure if `Map` can do any significant reduction. Because it is more like comparing than operating. It would be great if you can give some reference on the use of `Map` for comparing two data sets.

Comment: @Alex, can you check once more. I missed one } in the last table (`datavalue`). Otherwise the code works fine. And you have execute `data1` and `data2` before executing the code.

Comment: Well, for instance you could Map through data1. For each element in data1, you look for a corresponding element in data2:

Comment: `{#[[1]], #[[2]], 
   Sequence @@ Cases[data2, {#[[1]], x_Real} :> x]} & /@ data1`
Note how Sequence is used to splice the list returned by Cases directly into the {} list. As a hint, Sequence is generally Apply'ed (Sequence@@ in short). Is the rest of this code clear? By the way, this example code will not remove elements which are only in data1 but not in data2.

Comment: Thanks @TheoTiger. It is very helpful. And if for a date there is a data in first set and no data in second one, the `NumberQ` within the `Do` will return `False` and there will be no output.